# Java; Can't understand the structure of given assignment

Tags: java, structure

We've got an assignment a while ago which says we should make a Java program that gives us the instersection and union of two sets (is 'set' right? I'm livin in Germany). Anyways, there is this structure the Prof. has given us, and we should just fill out the needed code.

Here's what he gave us:

```
public class CharSet {
    // Attributes
    private char[] set; // set as Array
    private int size; // number of set's elements

    // Constructors
    public CharSet() { ... }
    public CharSet(char[] set) { ... }

    // get-/set-methods
    public char[] getSet() { ... }
    public int getSize() { ... }
    public void setSet(char[] a) { ... }

    // Method-overlay of the class 'Object'
    public boolean equals(Object x) { ... }
    public String toString() { ... }

    // Methoden application
    public CharSet intersection(CharSet c) { ... }
    public CharSet union(CharSet c) { ... }

    // main-method
    public static void main(String[] args) { ... }
}
```

Also, translated quote:

> Fill out the given Class. The method equals(Object x) shall return
>   true if the current set and parameter x are equal. [...] The method
>   toString() shall give out the current set as {2,b,a,x}. Of course you
>   can add attributes and methods to the Class. You may use methods of 
>   the String Class, but are not allowed to import any Classes
>
> Input:
>
> ```
> java CharSet {2,a,b,x} {b,1,2,3,a} {0,1,A,3,a}
> ```
>
> Possible Output:
>
> ```
> Union of the first two sets: {2,a,b,x,1,3}
> Intersection of the first two sets: {b,2,a}
> Union of all three sets: {2,a,b,x,1,3,0,A}
> Intersection of all three sets: {a}
> ```

If he wouldve just gave me the assignment without the given structure I would definitely have completed everything 2 weeks ago, but like this ...
I've got around 3 days left now, and I've done research for about 4 days and still couldn't figure out how to understand his given Class.
It wouldnt bother me to get the lowest grade on this assignment (which means I cant write the exam), but it does bother me a lot that I dont understand how to deal with it. I literally get angry about myself for not understanding what others might grasp very easily.

I would really appreciate it if there would be someone to take some time and try to explain to me what the though behind that Class is... I mean, for example, what do the two CharSets and get/set methods have to do?! I could code something with max 3 methods that solves everything perfectly fine.
My personal solution would be something about 200 lines mainly using for loops with list.contains and list.add but it doesn't fit into his given form... meh

Happy New Year :b

Comment: So you don't know what the method and constructors are supposed to do?

Comment: I'm in a tunnel vision only seeing my own solution :/
Yes, this structure given, I have no idea what they are supposed to do. Else I would've coded everything already.

Answer (score 2):

Your professors task is quite straight forward if you at least know some basic java. 
However, the structure of how the methods and constructors are written makes it somewhat confusing when looking at the example.

To answer your questions:
The get and set-methods are supposed to return and set the variables in the class.

To give you a hands-on example:

```
public class CharSet {
// Attributes
    private char[] set; // set as Array
    private int size; // number of set's elements

// Constructors
public CharSet() { 
    this.size = 0;
    this.set = new char[this.size];
}

public CharSet(char[] set) {
    this.set = set;
    this.size = set.length;
}

// get-/set-methods
public char[] getSet() { 
    return this.set;
}

public void setSet(char[] a) { 
    this.set = a;
}

}
```

When it comes to the union and the intersection-methods you will have to use loops and create a new array of chars that you can use when creating a new CharSet that you will be returning.

toString and equal-methods are supposed to [toString] return a string representation of this CharSet and return true or false answering the question wether this CharSet is equal to another object. 
In the equals-method you will need to do some class-comparing and casting to be able to access its internal variables if it is of the type CharSet.

Example:

```
CharSet other = null;
if(x instanceof CharSet) {
    other = (CharSet) x;
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

A bit of help, to combine with the other answers:

```
for (int i = 0; i < set.length; ++i) {
    char ch = set[i];
    ...
```

Or

```
for (char ch : set) {
```

And then

```
    boolean found = false;
    for (char otherCh : charSet.getSet()) {
         if (ch == otherCh) {
             found = true;
             break;
         }
    }
```

Using fixed sized `char[]` you maybe need first to count the matches, in order to know the array size of the result: `new char[n]`.

As String is allowed, you can use that to compose a growing result. The following would remove duplicate chars:

```
String result = "";
for (char ch : set) {
    if (result.indexOf(ch) == -1) {
        result += ch;
    }
}
set = result.toCharArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my attempt at providing descriptions for all of the methods / attributes so that it may help you understand:

```
// This is the set of characters represented as an array
// If the set is {a, b, c} then this array will have the elements
// a, b, and c is some order (order doesn't matter in a set)
private char[] set;
// This is the size of the set. If the set is {a, b, c} then the size is 3
private int size;

// Constructors
// This creates an empty set
public CharSet() { ... }
// This creates a set with the given characters in it. It is presumed
// that the parameter to this constructor may have repeated
// characters so as they are added to this set they must be 
// filtered out. For example if [a, b, c, c] is the parameter
// then the set will become {a, b, c}
public CharSet(char[] set) { ... }

// get-/set-methods
// This method returns this set as an array
// So if this set is {a, b, c} then this will return
// [a, b, c] or [a, c, b] or [c, a, b] or etc...
// all of these are valid outputs of this method
public char[] getSet() { ... }
// This method returns the size of this set
// If this set is {a, b, c} then this will return 3
public int getSize() { ... }
// This method throws away the current contents of this set
// and replaces them with the given characters. Again the input
// here may have duplicate characters so that has to be taken care of
// For example if the set was {a, b, c} and this method was called with 
// [b, c, d, d], then this set will become {b, c, d}
public void setSet(char[] a) { ... }

// Method-overlay of the class 'Object'
// This will return true if and only if 'x' is a CharSet that has the
// same characters as this CharSet. (Note: order of array representation
// does not matter)
public boolean equals(Object x) { ... }
// This will print this set as a String. For example if the set was 
// {a, b, c} then "{a, b, c}" or "{a, c, b}" or etc... is printed
public String toString() { ... }

// Methoden application
// This method returns the intersection of this set and the set given
// The set intersection will contain only elements common to both
// this set and the other set.
public CharSet intersection(CharSet c) { ... }
// This method returns the union of this set and the set given
// All elements of this set and the other set will be in the set union
public CharSet union(CharSet c) { ... }

// main-method
// This method is used for testing this class presumeably
public static void main(String[] args) { ... }
```